# How to display the button transperent in iphone

Tags: iphone, button, transparent

I am new to iphone development.I have text on the button.I want only test to be displayed and not the button border or color .It should be transparent such that only there is text in view and not the button.It is possible to do that in interface builder?Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Custom" as the button's type in the inspector. However, I would recommend against such design unless it's really necessary because if a button doesn't look like a button it may be confusing to your users.